# Set powershell variable if pipeline is empty

Tags: powershell

I've currently got this pipeline:

```
Get-R53HostedZones | where {$_.Name -eq 'myval'} | %{ Get-R53ResourceRecordSet -HostedZoneId $_.Id } | %{ $_.ResourceRecordSets | where {$_.Name.StartsWith("myval")} }
```

This works fine, it gives me the results I expect. Where I'm stumped is what I need to do next... I need to set a variable to `true` if this produces one or more results, and `false` if it's empty.

Comment: use an `if` statement: e.g. `$x = if ( '123','abc' | ?{$_ -eq 'xxx'} ) { $true } else  { $false }`.  If there's a possibility of the pipeline producing a single `false` result which would adversely affect the if statement, you can do: `$x = if (( '123','abc' | ?{$_ -eq 'xxx'} | measure-object).Count -gt 0) { $true } else  { $false }`

Comment: Do you need to? Could you `$results = @(pipeline); foreach ($r in $results) {...}` and if there are no results, the loop won't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign it to a variable, and check it with an `if` statement:

```
$MyRecords = @(Get-R53HostedZones | where {$_.Name -eq 'myval'} | %{ Get-R53ResourceRecordSet -HostedZoneId $_.Id } | %{ $_.ResourceRecordSets | where {$_.Name.StartsWith("myval")} })
if($MyRecords.Count -gt 0) { $true } else { $false }
```

The array subexpression operator (`@()`) makes sure that an array is returned, even if the result is only a single item. Otherwise the `Count` property won't exist fail in earlier versions of PowerShell

You can also do:

```
if ($MyRecords) { $true } else { $false }
```

But the first method makes it more clear what you're actually testing and will also work in situations where an expression might return the value `$false`